# Haskell and Cabal missing after El Capitan update

Tags: haskell, ghc, cabal, osx-elcapitan

Following an upgrade to OS X El Capitan, Cabal and GHC are no longer found on my system:

```
-bash: ghc: command not found
-bash: cabal: command not found
```

What do I need to do to get Cabal and GHC working on OS X El Capitan?

Comment: If you can, please create an issue for this on the HP github site so it can be tracked: https://github.com/haskell/haskell-platform/issues Also - do the programs still exist in /usr/bin (but are not executable) or has upgrading completely removed them?

Comment: Upgrading purges all of `/usr` (except `/usr/local`) of anything not from Apple.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I've found the following approach most reliable on all versions of OSX including El Capitan.

1. [Install Homebrew](http://brew.sh/)
2. Run `brew install ghc`
3. Run `brew install cabal-install`

This approach allows you to easily install the latest versions and have multiple versions installed and easily switch between them using the `brew switch` command. Haskell Platform lacks these properties, which is why the advanced users tend to avoid it any way.

Comment: That's a good idea. How do I get rid of my existing Haskell Platform installation (I'd like to clean that up first)? Will my existing packages in `/Users/Roy/Library/Haskell/ghc-7.10.2-x86_64/lib` remain, and can I still use them?

Comment: You can simply delete the files (the installation and package dirs) in case there's no better way. I wouldn't expect any conflicts to arise though even if you don't do anything. The Brew-installed Cabal uses a different directory structure, so you'd have to mess around a little to keep the packages, but I'd rather just drop them and let Cabal do its job and install them when required.

Comment: Sounds promising. Where does Homebrew put installed packages? For that matter where did it put the executables for `stylish-haskell` and `hlint`— I can't find them?

Comment: I also seem to have a `~/Library/Haskell` still around, which I assume I should remove (Homebrew `cabal install` shouldn't be putting things there right?)

Comment: Right. You can just drop the old stuff. Both libraries and executables of the "homebrewed" setup get installed in subdirs of `~/.cabal`.

Answer (score 10):

**Edit: There is now a [released version](https://www.haskell.org/platform/mac.html#osx-none) that fixes these issues.**

This is all caused by the new "[rootless security](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/193368/what-is-the-rootless-feature-in-el-capitan-really)" features in El Capitan.

You don't need to copy or reinstall the programs -- the files in `/usr/bin` were always just symlinks, to things available in `/Library/Frameworks/GHC.framework/` and `/Library/Frameworks/HaskellPlatform.framework`. So you should be able to symlink them again (to `/usr/local/bin` this time) from there.

See also https://github.com/haskell/haskell-platform/issues/205

Hopefully a new platform release that fixes these issues will be out soon.

Comment: FWIW, I tested the candidate out last night, and it seems to work perfectly. (And I already reported this to sclv last night, so this doesn't count as an extra report of success.)

Answer (score 1):

I believe El Capitan does not allow users to change `/usr` anymore which is where the Haskell binaries are installed.

If you can copy/install the programs into `/usr/local/bin` they should work from there.

If the programs are not visible anymore in /usr/bin, I would suggest reinstalling the HP into a different partition. Then copy them to /usr/local.

Let me know how it goes.

Comment: Any idea whether an update of GHC or Cabal is planned that will address this. Manually moving things around seems a bit fragile.

Comment: BTW: Copying isn't an option since it appears the EC install removes anything it dislikes in `/usr`.